# What is the browser variable at nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js

I just learned about nighwatchjs and try to understand the framework to write my tests.
Upon the examples I can notice the api using the variable browser - for which I could not find any more information on API Reference or any external docs.

I think I understood the concept of page object design pattern and I am experienced in using selectors etc.

But I would like to find out more about the browser object that is used as it confuses me what is really going on:

Consider this example:

```
this.demoTestGoogle = function (browser) {
  browser
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
    .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
    .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
    .click('button[name=btnG]')
    .pause(1000)
    .assert.containsText('#main', 'The Night Watch')
    .end();
};
```

I can understand that it uses the google url and will wait 1000ms to have the body tag visible, entering nightwatch value, waiting, clicking a button, pausing to have something done and do some assertions.
But still the browser variable is pretty anonymous to me - what can I do with it further more?

Comment: Any chance of getting marking one of the answers as accepted?? Would help other people landing on this page and this is, after all, a Q&A forum ;)

Comment: Actually no because for me it is still not well answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the nightwatch documentation - https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue

Here is the usage definition,

> When Nightwatch runs a test, it processes its commands in a list known as the command queue. This list manages the asynchronous execution of the commands defined in that test.
>
> As a queue, the command queue generally follows the rule of first in, first out (FIFO). The first command you call in a test is the first executed when the test runs. The second command is called next, followed by the next command up until the last command added, which becomes the last command executed.
>
> `The command API in Nightwatch - accessible via the object passed into test cases, usually called "client" or "browser" - consists of a collection of methods that are used to construct the command queue.` When you call a Nightwatch command such as click(), you're not sending the Selenium client the command to immediately click something, at least not right away. That method instead adds a "click" command to the command queue. After the test case function has resolved, something it does synchronously (commands are non-blocking), it traverses the command queue as defined by the Nightwatch commands you called, running through the queue executing each command in it asynchronously.

Reference to command API - http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#commands

Answer (score 3):

I know the [Commands documented at nightwatchjs.org](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#commands) describe what the `browser` object can do.

Let me know if this helps. I'm just learning myself, but I'll try share what I know about these commands.

Answer (score 2):

The browser object is the essential foundation of all tests since it represents, literally, the browser (or session) environment. I write **environment**, per se, since it is misleading to say that browser, in this context, is equal to the current window, since you could for example be running tests headlessly with PhantomJS.

You can do a number of cool things with the browser object. In my Nightwatch config I set a custom globals.js file under `globals_path` which allows me to access global variables like so:

`browser.globals.someFunction(browser.globals.someVariable);`

This is also where you actually use all of the commands of the Nightwatch API. So, to maximise the window of the currently running environment, you could use:

`browser.maximizeWindow();`

before, say, pointing the browser to the URL you would like to test:

`browser.url(www.example.com);`

The reason the browser object might look a little strange in the example you posted is because of how Nightwatch supports and allows all of its commands to be [chained](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) (link to command chaining example using jQuery - same principles apply).

It does look awfully pretty, when chained, doesn't it!? But you don't have to chain your tests. You can simply write `browser.` before each command you wish to send to the session.

Browser, by the way, is not a reserved word here. You can call it whatever you want. I actually use the word 'client' since I thought the word 'browser' was misleading, since I also run tests on PhantomJS alongside Chrome and Firefox.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm sure you will get it ;) perhaps you could choose an accepted answer, if you think your OP has been satisfied? ;)